# What is the name of this plant and how do I propagate it via stem?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, propagation, growing-medium

I have the following plant and wanted to know the name and then how to propagate it by stem. Thanks
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Jasmine of some sort. If it is, and it is probably easy to experimentally propagate in any case, just cut off some of the lower leaves, dip in rooting hormone, and wrap it around a damp toilet/paper towel and put it in a vase or even a pot with rich soil.